# cargar datos en una FlatList - react native

Tags: react-native

**Buen día, estoy trayendo mis datos a una FlatList pero no se muestran los datos, y la ruta get está funcionando, si alguien me puede ayudar se los agradecería.**

//ruta funcionando
https://portal.tuparcero.com/apiTuparcero/vehiculos/vehiculos.php?id=40

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-microservice-80q49x?file=/src/App.js:0-1034

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import { FlatList, Text, View } from "react-native";

function App() {
  const [listaLibros, setListaLibros] = useState([]);

  const peticionGet = async () => {
   await axios
      .get(
        `https://portal.tuparcero.com/apiTuparcero/vehiculos/vehiculos.php?id=40`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setListaLibros(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      peticionGet();
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  const Item = ({ item }) => (
    <View>
      <View>
        <View>
          <Text>{item.email}</Text>
          <Text>{item.tipo_usuario}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={listaLibros}
        renderItem={Item}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Buenas, he probado tu url que funciona... no devuelve una lista, devuelve un objeto, recuerda que en json las lista son así: `[{"nombre":"Pepe"}, {"nombre":"Carlos"}]` los array con Json empiezan con `[` pero en tu caso empieza con `{`, no sé si es una posible solución, pero de primeras me choca esto. Sino, la linea `const [listaLibros, setListaLibros] = useState([]);` está esperando un array... seguro que esperas un array?

Comment: pero como quedaria en mi codigo ?

Answer (score 0):

puede solucionar, solo fue remplazar `setListaLibros(response.data);` por `setListaLibros([response.data]);`